# Error in using Stdin.readLineSync(); in dart

Tags: dart

in vs code, i am getting this error in the basic input taking code from the user
my complete code:

import 'dart:io';

```
void main(){
  stdout.write("Enter your name : ");
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();
  stdout.write(name);
}
```

Error in the compiler:

```
playground.dart:9:23: Error: Method not found: 'Stdin.readLineSync'.
  String name = Stdin.readLineSync();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you are running the code using Dart VM and not compiled to JavaScript?

Comment: @julemand101 sorry for asking turns out I've been executing the old file after making changes to it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception "Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded" on VSCode when reading values with Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946458/exception-global-evaluation-requires-a-thread-to-have-been-loaded-on-vscode-wh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn dart as console application you should use  IntelliJ IDEA IDE. 
This is the best IDE for dart.
vscode, dartpad does not support stdin stdout.

Answer (score 4):

You must add:

```
import 'dart:io';
```

before your main function

Answer (score 1):

stdin.readLineSync()!
use the '!' as I did below:

```
void main(){
  stdout.write("Enter your name : ");
  var name = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  stdout.write(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Console applications aren't running on VSCode. I assume that your code is named "main.dart" You can use directly from the VSCode terminal:

```
dart run main.dart
```

Error on debug console:
[image]

Running correct on terminal:
[image]

My VSCode version is: 1.85.2

Answer (score 0):

if you were getting error like

```
"Getter not found.'stdin'"
```

in VSCode check for the extension "dart" is installed on your VSCode then checkitout for run i.e dart run command

Answer (score 0):

The error you get with stdin.readLineSync() is due to null safety introduced in Dart 2.12. Just add (!)

```
var name = stdin.readLineSync()!;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write it -> stdout.writeln and also import the library for it, I amended the code for you below, and it works fine on VSCode

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
      stdout.writeln("Enter your name : ");
      var name = stdin.readLineSync();
      stdout.write(name);
    }
```

Comment: Also make sure to install the Dart Extension in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Overall it's not good practice to use a null assertion operator `!` whereby you're personally guaranteeing to the compiler that the variable in question will never have a null reference. In this case, it may be more prudent to write:

`String? name = stdin.readLineSync();`

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-io/dart-io-library.html