# Dartlang- How do I pass user input to an async funtion?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I'm using Dart and brand new to async programming. I want a user inputted text field to be submitted to an API async function and then return the results. I simply can't get my head around it and can't find information to help anywhere. I assume my issue is that I am incorrectly combining sync and async programming somehow?

(I am using VSCode)

Any help much appreciated.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

Future<String> createRegDetailsMessage(String regFromUser) async {
  var regDetails = await fetchRegDetails(regFromUser);
  return 'Retrieved Data: $regDetails';
}

Future<String> fetchRegDetails(String regPassedOn) =>
    // Imagine that this function is
    // more complex and slow.
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => regPassedOn,
    );

Future<void> searchForDetails(String foo) async {
  print('Searching for Vehicle information...');
  print(await createRegDetailsMessage(foo));
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print('Registraion to be found:');
  var regToFind = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('$regToFind - confirmed');
  await searchForDetails(regToFind);
}
```

Error message from VScode :Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded

Comment: `var regToFind = stdin.readLineSync(); print( await fetchRegDetails(regToFind));` does not work?

Comment: I get this error:
Registraion to be found:
abc123
Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded

Comment: `abc123` what is it?

Comment: abc123-User input. It is just a generic test string representation of a registration

Comment: this works on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/: `main() async {
  var regToFind = 'foo bar ';
  print(regToFind);
  print( await fetchRegDetails(regToFind));
}

Future<String> fetchRegDetails(String regPassedOn) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => regPassedOn * 2,);
`

Comment: Hi! I tried your code, it works for me) prints: `Registraion to be found:
123abc
123abc - confirmed
Searching for Vehicle information...
Retrieved Data: 123abc`

Comment: am I misunderstood something?

Comment: Intriguing..... This is the desired functionality!  However VSCode gives me the error as follows:[Global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded]  If I hardcode the string as suggested by pskink it works though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @pskink and @ Mol0ko. After your comments and much hunting, I have found the code is correct..... The issue is with VSCODE.

VSCode cannot handle -  stdin.readLineSync();

Running the code via terminal works as expected.

Here is a link to a SO page discussing the issue var regToFind = stdin.readLineSync();

[Error in using Stdin.readLineSync(); in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170772/error-in-using-stdin-readlinesync-in-dart)

Also here is a link to google group discussion of it  -https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/misc/c/RYBaw1U-aNo